SQLAlchemy: Invalid connection option "plant"
I am currently doing a project using FastAPI and SQLModel. So far everything has been working fine but since a few hours, I keep getting the same error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3302, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 445, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1238, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 704, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 179, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 177, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 386, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 668, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 881, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 877, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 641, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 604, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 119, in connect
    raise last_ex.with_traceback(None)
psycopg.ProgrammingError: invalid connection option "plant"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../PlantSwap/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    init_db()
  File ".../PlantSwap/test.py", line 9, in init_db
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 5868, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3252, in _run_ddl_visitor
    with self.begin() as conn:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3242, in begin
    with self.connect() as conn:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3278, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 148, in __init__
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2442, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3302, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 445, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1238, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 704, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 179, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 177, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 386, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 668, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 881, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 877, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 641, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 604, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../PlantSwap/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 119, in connect
    raise last_ex.with_traceback(None)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg.ProgrammingError) invalid connection option "plant"

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)

Interestingly at the end it says "sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg.ProgrammingError) invalid connection option "plant"". This might have something to do with my project revolving around Plants and me having changed some environments variables. However, when I tried creating a minimal working example the same error occured. The following is the minimum 'working' example:
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, create_engine, Session

DATABASE_URL = "postgresql+psycopg://user:password@localhost/dbname"

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)


def init_db():
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)


def get_session():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        yield session


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_db()
    with get_session() as session:
        pass

So now I am thinking that it must either have something to do with the database (which I haven't changed at all - it's a postgres docker instance. I have already restarted it in the past using a script and doing so again doesn't change anything) or it has something to do with some environment variables I don't know of.
The entire project can be found here, as one can see the last GitHub action completed succesfully and if I try downloading the project code from GitHub and running it locally the same error occurs.
I have been able to pinpoint the issue further: There seems to be something wrong with my dependencies. I use uv for dependecy management and debugging the minimum working example I found this interesting looking file in my dependencies. The following is taken from:
.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/_psycopg_common.py
...
    def create_connect_args(self, url):
        opts = url.translate_connect_args(username="plant", database="dbname")
...

I think the username value pair should probably not be plant. I have no idea how it got there, however. And deleting the .venv and reinstalling it using uv sync creates the same file.

You've provided a "minimum 'working' example", which won't help anyone help you. Please provide a minimal example that actually reproduces the same error. I would be interested in seeing what the actual database connection string (DATABASE_URL in your example) looks like.

@M.O. That is the actual DATABASE_URL string. I literally run that python file and the problem occurs.

Since that is not the actual url of the database, that would indicate that the issue is before connecting to the database, see the edit (1).

Uummmmmm, that looks really weird, and is not in the source code. I would try running something like uv remove sqlalchemy; uv cache clean; uv add sqlalchemy to try and get a clean copy.

@M.O. Wow, what a mess ... I tried that, didn't work. Then I reinstalled uv and deleted the .venv altoghther again, cleaned the uv cache and now it seems to work. So it had something todo with uv I guess?

I think it might have happened after a refactor using pycharm where I changed a variable named userto plant. That would be pretty insane tho and sound like a bug on pycharms' side

Yeah, that was my best guess too, some kind of search/replace gone overboard. It's also really weird that uv would recreate the file in the same state... Well, glad you've got it working! Hopefully this is a once-in-a-lifetime bug *knock on wood
